# hadoop ulimit open files name

Tags: hadoop, ulimit

I have a hadoop cluster we assuming is performing pretty "bad". The nodes are pretty beefy.. 24 cores, 60+G RAM ..etc. And we are wondering if there are some basic linux/hadoop default configuration that prevent hadoop from fully utilizing our hardware.

There is a [post](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/03/configuration-parameters-what-can-you-just-ignore/) here that described a few possibilities that I think might be true.

I tried logging in the namenode as root, hdfs and also myself and trying to see the output of `lsof` and also the setting of `ulimit`. Here are the output, can anyone help me understand why the setting doesn't match with the open files number.

For example, when I logged in as root. The `lsof` looks like this:

```
[root@box ~]# lsof | awk '{print $3}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
   7256 cloudera-scm
   3910 root
   2173 oracle
   1886 hbase
   1575 hue
   1180 hive
    801 mapred
    470 oozie
    427 yarn
    418 hdfs
    244 oragrid
    241 zookeeper
     94 postfix
     87 httpfs
         ...
```

But when I check out the `ulimit` output, it looks like this:

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 806018
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 10240
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 1024
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

I am assuming, there should be no more than 1024 files opened by one user, however, when you look at the output of `lsof`, there are 7000+ files opened by one user, can anyone help explain what is going on here? 
Correct me if I had made any mistake understanding the relation between `ulimit` and `lsof`.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check limits for the process. It may be different from your shell session:

Ex:

```
[root@ADWEB_HAPROXY3 ~]# cat /proc/$(pidof haproxy)/limits | grep open
Max open files            65536                65536                files     
[root@ADWEB_HAPROXY3 ~]# ulimit -n
4096
```

In my case haproxy has a directive on its config file to change maximum open files, there should be something for hadoop as well

Comment: can you tell me how to find the `pid of haproxy` in this case? Is that a hadoop proxy user or what?

Comment: Forget about haproxy, I am just illustrating  that open files may vary for processes and pointed where to find the limits for a given pid.

Comment: BTW pidof is a command which returns pid based on process name. In you case pidof java.

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar issue, which caused one of the claster's YARN TimeLine server to stop due to reaching magical 1024 files limit and crashing with "too many open files" errors.

After some investigation it came out that it had some serious issues with dealing with too many files in TimeLine's LevelDB. For some reason YARN ignored yarn.timeline-service.entity-group-fs-store.retain-seconds setting (by default it's set to 7 days, 604800ms). We had LevelDB files dating back for over a month.

What seriously helped was applying a fix described in here: https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/48735/application-timeline-server-manage-the-size-of-the.html

Basically, there are a couple of options I tried:

**Shrink TTL (time to live) settings** First enable TTL:

```
<property>
 <description>Enable age off of timeline store data.</description>
 <name>yarn.timeline-service.ttl-enable</name>
 <value>true</value>
</property>
```

Then set yarn.timeline-service.ttl-ms (set it to some low settings for a period of time):
\

```
<property>
 <description>Time to live for timeline store data in milliseconds.</description>
 <name>yarn.timeline-service.ttl-ms</name>
 <value>604800000</value>
</property>
```

**Second option, as described, is to stop TimeLine server, delete the whole LevelDB and restart the server**. This will start the ATS database from scratch. Works fine if you failed with any other options.

To do it, find the database location from yarn.timeline-service.leveldb-timeline-store.path, back it up and remove all subfolders from it. This operation will require root access to the server where TimeLine is located.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I had the same issue on HDP 2.5 and the option to stop App Timeline Server  and removing all contents under "yarn.timeline-service.leveldb-timeline-store.path" helped me. I also set the yarn.timeline-service.ttl-ms to a shorter time to minimize the issue from happening in the future. Thanks for the tips.